# In creating a stack using linked list ,how do we determine the size of the heap and what assigns the value to it?

Tags: data-structures, singly-linked-list

So I created a stack using a linked list, the tutorial says that to check whether the heap is full we will check if we can create a node or not . If we can create one then the stack is not full and otherwise, it is full, now how does the computer know what's the actual size we want to create .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) is thrown if your attempt to allocate memory fails.

Catch that exception, and you've determined that the heap is unable to fulfill your request.